# Problem setting up edge rendering function

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph, and I want my `EdgeRenderingFunction` to colour the edges based on the vertex they originate from. In this toy example, I'm trying to get the edge originating from vertex 1 to be red:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 5 -> 3, 5 -> 4, 
  1 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 3}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[First[#1] === 1, {Red, Line[#1]}, 
     Line[#1]] &), VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: bad]

What am I doing wrong? I was following the (slightly more complicated) model given in the *Mathematica* documentation:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 5 -> 3, 5 -> 4, 
  1 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 3}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[
     Length[#1] > 2, {Red, Line[#1], 
      Text[If[First[#1] === Last[#1], "loop", "multiedge"], 
       LineScaledCoordinate[#1, .7], Background -> White]}, 
     Line[#1]] &), VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: good]

Comment: Maybe `GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 5 -> 3, 5 -> 4, 
  1 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 3}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[First[#2] === 1, {Red, Line[#1]}, 
     Line[#1]] &), VertexLabeling -> True]` ?

Comment: hmm, why then in the documentation example does #1 work? I thought the first argument is the x->y connections?

Comment: I just read the first point under More Information [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeRenderingFunction.html?q=EdgeRenderingFunction&lang=en) and it seems that you need the vertices (2nd argument).

Comment: Ah, mis-read "beginning and end points" as "beginning and end vertices". Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 5 -> 3, 5 -> 4, 1 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 3},
          EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[MemberQ[#2, 1], {Red, Line[#1]}, Line[#1]] &),
          VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: graph with red edges]

The docs for `EdgeRenderingFunction` are a bit subtle, but there is the note that any such function must take the vertices as the second argument.

Comment: Thanks, although to be precise, direction matters, but otherwise, this is the answer I was looking for

Comment: In that case, replace `MemberQ[#2, 1]` with `First[#2] == 1`.

Comment: @J.M. Out of curiosity, how come the image is flipped ?

Comment: I don't quite know why, @b.gatessucks. That's how it came out on the machine I'm using (8.0.4 on Fedora 17).

Comment: @J.M. Same setup at home, will try later.

Comment: @J.M. No flip for me. Weird.